# Set multiple inputs to string with index

Tags: vue.js

I´m new to vue and have to send a form. The backend is giving me a number on how many strings my members array has to contain. Each string contains firstName and lastName (e.g ["Peter Becker", "Henry White"]). Therefore the UI has to have two inputs. My form looks like this

```
             <div v-for="(n, index) in retailer.slotCount" :key="index" 
               class="form-input">
                <b-form-group>
                  <label>Gast {{index + 1}}</label>
                  <b-row>
                    <b-col md="5">
                      <b-form-input v-model="form.firstName[index]" />
                    </b-col>
                    <b-col md="5">
                      <b-form-input v-model="form.lastName[index]" />
                    </b-col>
                  </b-row>
                </b-form-group>
              </div>
```

Here my problem starts when I want to dispatch the form two my POST action

```
 methods: {
    bookDate() {
      this.$store
        .dispatch("sendBooking", {
          eventId: Math.floor(this.event.id),
          participants: `${this.form.firstName} ${this.form.lastName}`
        })
    }
  },
```

The sent data is "firstName", "firstname", "lastName", "lastName"

How can I combine firstName and lastName into one string and put them in an array. Does anybody has a quick solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
array.push(`${this.form.firstName}` `${this.form.lastName}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `var thestring = yourIndex.toString;` to set all of the indexes to a single string.